# Is using Answerer is correct?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, american-english, british-english

If there is a position in a company that answers questions related to for example physics, what is the best word that describes this position?

"Answerer of Questions related to Physics"  ?

Comment: **Physics Expert**? There's ["Medical Physics Expert"](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=medical+physics+expert+definition) that means *...an individual or, if provided for in national legislation, a group of individuals, having the knowledge, training and experience to act or give advice on matters relating to radiation physics applied to medical exposure,...*

Comment: Maybe in a start-up, but that would be an exceedingly unprofessional title in a company.

Answer (score 2):

As well as the straight *expert* answers already provided, you also have the common corporate concept of a *subject matter expert* or *SME* (also *domain expert* in certain contexts). [Wikiref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject-matter_expert):

> A **subject-matter expert** (**SME**) or **domain expert** is a person who is an authority in a particular area or topic.

I know Wikipedia isn't the best of dictionary-style resources, but it's probably too jargon-ish to have made it to the real world just yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best word in that case is **expert**. This suggests that the person is the company's authority on the subject of physics. If the position is more public-oriented and the person is not necessarily the expert, but just the one who answers questions, consider **guide** or **resource**.

Answer (score 0):

In court, the term is "expert" witness when any technical consultation is necessary.

If the trial is about computer programming, say, than an "expert" witness is called to testify. The same term is used in any profession or practice.

In order to be an "expert," local jurisprudence suggests the level of expertise required, such as published work, professional involvement, or academic achievement in the field.